# How to make my cinnamon rolls less bready?

Tags: baking, cinnamon, rolls

I make it like this 3/4 cup milk, 1/4 margarine, 3/4 flour, 25 ounce yeast, 1/4 white sugar, 1/4 water, one egg.

I leave it for thirty minutes, and it hardly rises. When cooked, the taste and texture are a bit too bready. How do I make it less bready?

Didn't write the filling because that turns out right, I just have problem with the dough itself.
I use self-rising dough meant for cake.

Comment: Are you looking for more cakey or more biscuity?

Comment: Scott Downey, I'm looking for more cakey, like what you get at Dunkin Doughnuts.

Comment: You've stated the ingredients but not how you prepare them, which can make a world of difference. Also, 25 ounces of yeast is a lot. And what does the last statement mean?

Comment: Thirty minutes is a very short time for proofing, you won't get a decent rise. Why so short?

Comment: Erm... Are you buying yeast dough? The "25 oz yeast" seems to indicate this.

Answer (score 2):

This is borderline unclear what you're asking but I'll take a shot at it. Cinnamon rolls are made using a fortified yeast dough. Fortified means that there is butter/shortening and/or eggs added, which slow down the yeast action.

There are a few things that aren't right with what you are doing.

1. you are using self-rising flour in a recipe that is supposed to be leavened by yeast. Self rising flour is usually lower in gluten content and contains leavening agents. You want to use regular flour so you get the right gluten content, also you may not have the right acid balance for your self-rising flour which could lead to the leavening agents not working and adding off flavors. You don't need the leavening agents if you are doing it right
2. too much yeast: I think you aren't adding 25oz of yeast, but if you are then one packet is enough!
3. I don't think you have the right balance between moisture and flour. Your recipe has 1 cup of water and milk to 3/4 cup flour, this will make a batter, not a dough. You need to at least triple the amount of flour
4. too short a rising time: 30 minutes is simply not enough time for the yeast to work. You need to wait until the dough at least doubles in size, which usually takes between 1-2 hours. You need to aim for the amount of rise, not a time as there are many factors which can affect this. If it's not rising at all then you've got dead yeast - either it's gotten too old, been exposed to too much heat, or exposed to salt

I suggest you start with an entirely different recipe as the one you have put up has a lot which needs to be fixed. Given that there's not nearly enough flour and you are not proofing it anywhere near long enough I can't see you getting a decent result.